# Show progress in rendering React Native Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I have a React Native app with a MapView (`react-native-maps`).
The MapView is fullscreen and when a user navigates to the screen with this MapView a couple things happen:

1. fetch requests are made to get lists of coordinates, which are then stored locally in a Realm database. (The requests are only made if the local data is out of sync with the server data).
2. for about 1000 routes, the coordinates are converted to Polyline objects which are rendered on the MapView. This is done by mapping an array of objects to Polylines.

The problem:
When all this is happening, the rendering of the screen can take up to 30 seconds on older/slower devices.
Right now i'm showing an ActivityIndicator while this is all loading, but I would like to show a progressbar i.e.

because `useState` is async, this doesn't update during rendering.
I tried to use `useSharedValue` from `react-native-reanimated`. This value is updated when I do `progress.value += 1` in the loop that does the fetch requests, but not in the map function that generates the polylines.

What i'd like to happen:
Let's assume we need to make 50 fetch requests, and render 1000 polylines. That means a total op 1050 actions.
Under the ActivityIndicator i'd like to show a progressbar that updates as actions are completed during the render process (1/1050 -> 2/1050). Right now i can do 1/1050 until 50/1050, but then the polyline rendering doesnt update the sharedValue.

1. Is this possible?
2. How?

Comment: useRef  may help if your problem is related to immediate dom manipulations.  You may try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-progress if issue is due to progress bar

Comment: @VisheshMangla i found that package, but it doesnt help. It's just a way to show progress, not track progress. I still need to reference a value which indicates the progress. Do you have an example on how to use useRef in this case? 

i tried initing it with const ref = useRef(0) and the in the loop ref.current += 1, but that doesnt seem to work

Comment: Maybe share a sandbox with your existing code so that people can try. https://snack.expo.dev/@wwoessi/sandbox